# Persistent lines using clay strips tool

Tags: sculpting

I'm having a persistent issue with the Clay Strips sculpting tool that results in a series of lines during stokes:

[image: Example]

Some things of note:

- Remeshing resolution doesn't make a difference, if anything the higher I go the worse it gets. The example has 1 million faces.
- I've tried adjusting the spacing between 1-5%. Again, no difference. (1% pictured).
- Adjusting tip roundness can alleviate it somewhat, but it doesn't go away regardless.
- The issue persists regardless if I use my tablet (with pressure sensitivity) or my mouse. In the above example, the left strokes are with a tablet, while the right was with a mouse.
- The scale is correctly set.

What makes this behaviour doubly bizarre is the somewhat consistent pattern it's exhibiting:

[image]

(The above image uses the tool reset to its default values).

I'm using 2.93. When I watch videos of people using this tool, they don't appear to have the same issue. Is there a setting I'm missing or something?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Normal Radius` for the brush to `1`. Not sure what it does exactly, but if it's set to anything higher, it will cause that strange, persistent pattern.

Other patterns can be caused by too low `Spacing` or too high `Hardness`.

Comment: It certainly diminishes the patterns when I do slow strokes in straight-on orthographic views, though not entirely. And as soon as I speed up, or try from a more natural angle, it rears its ugly head again.

Comment: As for how setting the normal radius functions, when you set it lower and try sculpting from various angles, it acts much less in a manner where it's thin strips building up on the underlying shape and more like a rapid build up on itself instead.